# How to configure and launch Opera capabilities on Selenoid

Tags: python, selenoid

Maybe somebody run into that problem. I try to launch test in Opera browser on Selenoid (https://aerokube.com/selenoid), but any time with many different version of docker image I got something error like this:

`selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: Missing or invalid capabilities(Driver info: operadriver=113.0.5672.127 (8da0c060b24fe8c84cb753bd0659e49fc290d3e8-refs/branch-heads/5672@{#1203}),platform=Linux 5.4.0-109-generic x86_64)`

For Opera options I use `ChromeOptions()`

`from selenium.webdriver import ChromeOptions`

````
selenoid_options = {"version": config["ver"],
                    "browserName": config["browser"],
                    "enableVNC": True,
                    "enableVideo": False
                    }

options.set_capability('selenoid:options', selenoid_options)
return webdriver.Remote(command_executor=f'http://{selenoid_host}:4444/wd/hub', options=options)```

Before it Ive got image for opera - selenoid/opera:99.0
There are in the output ```docker images``` on my Selenoid host.
Also I have in browser.json next item:

    "opera": {
        "default": "99.0",
        "versions": {
            "99.0": {
                "image": "selenoid/vnc_opera:99.0",
                "port": "4444",
                "path": "/"
            }

And Ive changed it for many versions and download again different docker images for it, but has no success.

Any ideas?
````

Answer (score 0):

Should be something like this:

```
"browserName": "opera",
"browserVersion": "99.0",
"selenoid:options": {
  "enableVNC": True,
  "enableVideo": False
}
```

Comment: Try to do that in runtime, by updating capabilities here ```self.start_session(capabilities)``` (lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py) but get the same problem

**{
 'browserName': 'opera',
 'selenoid:options': {
  'enableVNC': True,
  'enableVideo': False
 },
 'version': '99.0'
}**

{SessionNotCreatedException}Message: session not created: Missing or invalid capabilities
  (Driver info: operadriver=113.0.5672.127 (8da0c060b24fe8c84cb753bd0659e49fc290d3e8-refs/branch-heads/5672@{#1203}),platform=Linux 5.4.0-109-generic x86_64)

What doing I wrong?

Comment: I can see in UI Selenoid that session are created but this Exception - "{SessionNotCreatedException}Message: session not created: Missing or invalid capabilities" arise and block the launch. How could fix it?

**Connected!
Starting OperaDriver 113.0.5672.127 (8da0c060b24fe8c84cb753bd0659e49fc290d3e8-refs/branch-heads/5672@{#1203}) on port 4444
All remote connections are allowed. Use an allowlist instead!
OperaDriver was started successfully.

 --- x11vnc loop: 1 ---

 --- x11vnc loop: waiting for: 72

PORT=5900
**